# perforce diff to git

Tags: git, diff, perforce

Taking perforce diff when I try to patch this using `git am`, it says "Patch format detection failed".

How do I get my changes from perforce and apply it to git branch?

This is the first few lines of diff

```
==== //depot/a.c#162 - /asdf/a.c ====
4326a4327,4642
> /*
>  *----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  *
>  *  --
```

Comment: Check if `p4 diff` has an option to create an *unified diff*. `-u` might be worth a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you produce the diff with [`p4 diff -du`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/diff.html) to get the [unified diff format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format), which works much better with tools like [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch), and is (I believe) the only format that Git understands.

You also may need to edit the patch to take out the Perforce syntax; as you can see, the file name appears as `//depot/a.c#162`, which `patch` and `git apply` may be interpreting as the actual filename; `a.c#162`. Try removing the `#162` part if that appears in your patch.

And depending exactly where you are applying the patch, you may need to pass `-p1` to `patch` or `git apply` in order to strip off the leading `/`, or `-p2` to strip off the entire leading directory.

Comment: Any idea how to get the diff generated using `describe` to be recognized by `patch`?

Comment: Hi @Brian, is there any command to quickly delete all `#N`. Thanks!

Comment: @dien don't have Perforce in front of me to check the exact format, but something like `sed -Ee 's|(//.*)#[0-9]+|\1|' <input.patch >output.patch` should do the trick. This is fairly imprecise, so check that it produced something sensible before trying to apply the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git apply`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-apply), or failing that use [`patch(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) directly, then commit the results.

Comment: Why not, what errors do you get?  What's your perforce diff tool and why didn't it generate proper patch formats?

Comment: i did p4 diff > file and patch -p0 < /scratch/diffs/1st 
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
sreraku $ git apply /scratch/diffs/1st 
error: No changes

Comment: Well given that example, you're not applying the same patch file you created.  Is that a typo? Please edit your question and add the first 10 lines or so of `file`.

Comment: Did you try `patch -p1`? It looks like you have extra file path information there you don't want to use.

Comment: The diff output from perforce and git are incompatible by default. This will not work