# How to apply a Perforce patch?

Tags: diff, perforce, patch

I generated a patch some time ago using the `p4 diff` command.

However, now that I want to apply it, I realize that there is no way to apply a patch in Perforce.

Since I did not use the `-du` option, the patch is in that obscure perforce format and can't be applied with `patch(1)`. The original changes have been lost. Also, that patch is over 300kb long so manual editing isn't really an option.

What are my options ? Are there patch converters, or some Perforce extension allowing the application of these kind of patchs ?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289306/perforce-diff-to-git

Comment: you can probably convert with sed. this is also the rough format from gnu diff, so there is probably some reasonable tooling out there, keep  hope alive friend.

Comment: I'm trying to apply a patch saved by [`p4 describe -du`](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_describe.html). It gives an error with the unix patch command "Only garbage was found in the patch input."

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps Perforce's diff output format has changed, but @RumburaK's answer didn't work for me.

I had to modify it to convert the `====` header to diff's `+++` and `---` header format.

```
sed -Ee 's|==== (//.*)#[0-9]+(.*)|+++ \1\n--- \1|' < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

infile.txt was generated with the following command (where 12335 was a shelved changelist): `p4 describe -du -S 12345`

outfile.txt was applied with the following command: `patch -p3 -l < outfile.txt`

Comment: The GNU sed equivalent of `-E` is `-r` (but GNU sed accepts `-E` without documenting it)

Comment: You also need to 'cut off the head' of the describe output. I do this: `p4 describe -du -S <CL number here> | sed -Ee 's|==== //(.*)#[0-9]+(.*)|+++ \1\n--- \1|' | awk '/^+++ /{f=1}f'`

Answer (score 3):

Just found your question after saving some of my changes in a patch and reverting them in order to test some of the original code...

Assuming you're using a decent terminal emulator, this one time operation could take you up to an hour or so.

The good thing is that you can't run into this on a daily basis, as you probably will now use "-du" from now on, at least me I'm sure I will.
Just copy and paste the file name as prompted:

```
$ patch -i cucu.diff 
can't find file to patch at input line 2
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|==== //depot/foo/boo.cpp#1 - /home/who/perforce/foo/boo.cpp ====
--------------------------
File to patch: 

<double-click!> to copy
<middle-click!> to paste

File to patch: /home/who/perforce/foo/boo.cpp <CR>
```

Perhaps you will have 100 files in the patch... keep clicking :-)

If you're looking for a subst expression (vim, sed):

```
s/.* - \(.*\) ====/+++: \1/
```

But - beware if you added sources (whole files, p4 add) their content probably won't be printed in the diff - in which case nobody will be able to re-patch them in...

Comment: `sed -Ee 's/.* - \(.*\) ====/+++: \1/' <in.patch >out.patch`  gives `error: sed: 1: "s/.* - \(.*\) ====/+++: ...": \1 not defined in the RE`

Comment: @Koshmaar this happens because you added `-E`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks a lot - you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer:The `p4 diff2` command supports a `-u` flag to generate diffs in GNU diff format.

From `p4 help diff2`:

> The -u flag uses the GNU diff -u format and displays only files that differ. The file names and dates are in Perforce syntax, but the output can be used by the patch program.

Comment: This solution would seem to work only when comparing two files that are in the repository.  How can I get a GNU patch for the diff between my working file and the one in the repository?

Comment: p4 diff supports a unified diff option, ```-du[n] (unified)``` for working vs repository file diffs, but it isn't fully in GNU diff -u format.   In the past, I've used it and then edited the diff output to make it work with GNU patch.