# Perforce command line unified diff of a shelved ChangeList

Tags: git, sed, diff, perforce, patch

I know a number of ChangeList of my friend. I want to pass this CL number to a Bash script, which will generate a diff file read for the `patch` program (which will recreate the change in the git repo).

So far I have this:

```
function p4_shelved_cl_to_diff()
{
    p4 describe -S -du $1 > p4_diff.patch
}
```

It generates the diff, but headers are in p4 format:

```
==== //p4_repo/dir_in_repo/dir/file.cpp#123 (text) ===
```

whereas they should be in

```
--- dir/file.cpp
+++ dir/file.cpp
```

So what I'm looking for is a special p4 syntax (googled extensively, checked p4 manual – little hope) or **rather a sed/awk/whatever script that will do the change for me**.

Any ideas, or maybe someone has this already written?

Comment: Try the suggestion in this answer for converting those file headers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8289560/193453

Comment: And also this similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13609062/193453

Comment: Thanks. The second is closer to what I'm looking, but that sed expression doesn't work. Seems Benjamin W has working version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This substitution works for your example:

```
$ sed 's|^====.*/\([^/]*/[^#]*\).*===$|--- \1\n+++ \1|' infile
--- dir/file.cpp
+++ dir/file.cpp
```

It works on lines starting and ending with `====` (actually ending with `===`, but I believe that's just a typo in the question, and it will also work for lines ending with `====`).

It captures everything between the second to last `/` and the `#`, then adds the `---` and `+++` on separate lines.

Note that I haven't looked into the general format of p4 diff headers, so this might break in other cases – the better overall solution would be to fix what generates the wrong headers.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sed wizard, but looks good, I will try it in two weeks when back at work :) "Second to last /" and general format - in the real diffs that I got, the dir/file.cpp was actually sth like dir1/dir2/dir3/file.cpp . I think script should be getting parameter - name of last dir on repo, or the number of / to remove, to make it work in the more general sense. And yes, best would be to get p4 generate normal unified diff. I guess now it's not possible and I would have to very loudly complain on their forums and then wait few weeks/months for the fix.